# What does this line " export type Replace<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R; " do in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

With my current knowledge, I am not able to understand what the Replace type is.

I did read the typescript documentation and learned part of what's happening in that line but it still was not enough for me to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

The type `Replace` is replacing properties in `T`, with properties in `R`.

To break it down:

1. `Omit<T, keyof R>` removes properties from `T` those with same  name as properties in `R`.
2. Then `& R` intersects the resulting type from (1) with `R`. That means it adds the properties in `R` to the resulting type.

This may seem weird in that it re-adds the same properties to the resulting type those it removed earlier. But I suspect this was done to replace the type of the properties. Here is an example.

```
type Replace<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R;

type A = {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string,
  prop3: string,
  prop4: string
};

type B = {
  prop3: number,
  prop4: number
};


type X = Replace<A, B>;

const x: X = {
  prop1: '1',
  prop2: '2',
  prop3: 3,
  prop4: 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It remove the common key of T and R from T, then intersect the result with R

[image]

as you can see, the common key is `b`, `b` of A is `string`, now it is `boolean`(from `b` of `C`)

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggvAbwFBVVAhgLgHYFcC2ARhAE4A0KahmAzsCQJbYDmSAvkkqJFAMJRwoyNFGqEA9uIA2EdNkqoAxpgnTZ8jl3DQAShDBT0iiAB4AGmQCaAPgFQA8vgbBzZANYQQ4gGZQbUADI-Tm5oAAUSCGBgBm8Qc1tBBABtAGkoJigPL18zAF1MMzS8tigQ7SgAETsIqJi4kz0DI1MYMl5rayQAem60AD0AfiA)

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)